# Hibernate update with same column

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

SQL statement:

```
UPDATE table SET column = 'new_value' WHERE column = 'old_value'
```

(same column name)

How to do this in Hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

You may use EntityManager.merge() which can lead to NonUniqueObjectException if there are multiple results are found with same column name.

Better to use NamedQuery ot NativeNamedQuery to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you would want to perform batch updates.

I suggest you refer to this [link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch04.html)

You can make use of the below code in order to get this done.

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

String hqlUpdate = "update Customer c set c.name = :newName where c.name = :oldName";
int updatedEntities = s.createQuery( hqlUpdate )
    .setString( "newName", newName )
    .setString( "oldName", oldName )
    .executeUpdate();
tx.commit();
session.close();
```

Do note the below point mentioned in the link.

*Joins, either implicit or explicit, are prohibited in a bulk HQL query. You can use sub-queries in the WHERE clause, and the sub-queries themselves can contain joins.*